# Text is centering in view instead of trailing the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why is the "..." not trailing? it should be on the right of the screen always not the center.

```
ZStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Good morning")
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Spacer()
    }
    HStack {
        Text("...")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(alignment: .trailing)
            .font(.title3)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `Spacer`:

```
ZStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Good morning")
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Spacer()
    }
    HStack {
        Spacer() // <- add here
        Text("...")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            // .frame(alignment: .trailing) // can be removed
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.6, iOS 13.6.

---

You can read more about `.frame(alignment: .trailing)` here:

- [Alignment Guides in SwiftUI](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

Comment: I have already added another spacer before and it does not respond correctly @pawello2222

Comment: @RealTechyGod Did you copy my code and test it? Please paste the code above directly into the view body.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the answer is to remove the ZStack and add the spacer in the middle... Like This!

```
HStack {
    Text("Good morning")
        .padding(.leading, 20.0)
        .font(.subheadline)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    Spacer()
    
    Text("...")
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
        .font(.title3)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
}
```

This article is what helped (after input from @pawello2222)

- https://benmcmahen.com/using-spacer-in-swiftui/

Spacers are essentially `</span>` once you think of it like that it becomes logical.